# Why do I get a BIGINT overflow on MySQL only for some queries?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I've encountered a weird situation In MySQL5.7.

Of course, the below query is failed as I expected:

```
mysql> SELECT 18446744073709551615 + 1;
ERROR 1690 (22003): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(18446744073709551615 + 1)'
```

but the following query worked:

```
mysql> SELECT 18446744073709551616;
+----------------------+
| 18446744073709551616 |
+----------------------+
| 18446744073709551616 |
+----------------------+
```

How can it be possible? Is this expected behavior in MySQL or bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL, in the absence of explicit data type information, tries to determine the appropriate data types for literal values based on the value limits. Since the scale of 18446744073709551616 exceeds the allowed range for `UNSIGNED BIGINT`, it must be a `DECIMAL` then, which has a much larger range. You can see this in action by creating a table from your `SELECT`:

```
create table test as  SELECT 18446744073709551615, 18446744073709551616
```

and describing it:

```
describe test
```

which results in

```
Field                   Type                    Null    Key     Default     Extra
----------------------- ----------------------- ------- ------- ----------- -----------
18446744073709551615    bigint(20) unsigned     NO              0   
18446744073709551616    decimal(20,0)           NO              0
```

[dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=00e6a813e2d9a63a7db5fb5cbc21d4e9)